# schematic for verilog code that adds three inputs

Tags: verilog

What does the schematic looks like for the following verilog code?

```
module mystery2(s, c, x, y, z);
  input x, y, z;
  output s, c;
  assign {c, s} = x + y + z;
endmodule
```

I know that `{c, s}` means that they are concatenated, what does this looks like in schematics?
And x + y + z is just an add between the three inputs, right? And we have one wire coming out of it?

Comment: I am not asking someone here to solve the problem for me, I just want to know what does the add looks like in schematics....

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `x + y + z` as the sum of 3 1-bit wires, but the sum requires 2 bits.  Thus, I would consider `{c,s}` as 2 1-bit wires "coming out".

The answer to your main question depends on how the circuit is implemented.  There are many possible schematic representations for your code because you have described a digital logic function at a high level of abstraction.

Run that code through your synthesis tool and see what kind of a gate-level netlist is produced.  Then look at it in a schematic viewer.  Let the tools do the work for you.